# iOS9 reports app background usage when app is not running in the background

Tags: ios, ios9

We have an app that has UIBackgroundModes set to Audio because it offers streaming of audio inside the app. I have used the app over a period of 6 days and never used the streaming part but still iOS reports the app as having 1 hour of background usage and 3,2 hours on screen.

Is there any reason why the app would continue in the background if the audio is not active? I thought it would only do so if we actually played audio. When testing the app in debugger I don't see any activity after pressing the home button so it seems suspended to me but iOS9 seems to think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

with the BG mode, your app runs in the BG as long as it isn't killed by the user